# Laravel bootstrap/cache on GDrive giving error on composer install

Tags: php, laravel

trying to composer install a proj. on GDrive so I can continue dev on it without further ado from any machine. But bootstrap/cache, even when GDrive sync is turned off is giving me a headache with:

"

> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In PackageManifest.php line 178:

The C:...\bootstrap\cache directory must be present and writable.

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
"

I solved the rwx for the folder on GDrive sync app for my Win11, but the problem remains no matter what.

Question, is there another reason why the post-autoload-dump is kept from functioning respectively an idea available on working around this without losing my ability to post-autoload-dump ?

Regards Frank

Answer (score 0):

run "chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache" on the command line.

Comment: Please try for [answer].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).